# what's wrong in this code? how can I correct it?

Tags: graphics

```
 Show[Graphics[{{RGBColor[0.976577, 0.949233, 0.0195315], 
    Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}, Line[{{0, 0}, {-12, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 6}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {3.4, 6.5}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {6.8, 5.7}}], {RGBColor[0, 0.500008, 0], 
    Disk[{-10, 0}, {1, 2}]}, 
   Disk[{-10, 1}, {.6, 1.5}]}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 0.996109], 
   Disk[{5, 6}, {1.6, 1.3}], Arrow[{-12, 1.5}, {-10, 1.5}], 
   Arrow[{5, 6}, {7, 8}], Text["b", {-11.88, 0.857724}], 
   Text["j", {-11.4616, 2.392}], Text["Au", {-1.0059, 1.27616}], 
   Text["dN", {6.74052, 6.85534}], Text["dQ", {3, 74171, 7.483}], 
   Text["Q", {1.64952, 0.578765}], Text["db", {-8.88118, 0.997203}], 
   Text["a", {-12.0892, 1.97356}]}], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to figure this out is first to listen to the error messages.  You got as an error

> An improperly formatted option was encountered while reading a Graphics.

If you are new to *Mathematica* that may not mean anything to you, but it is answered by #1 below.  Next strategy is to cut everything out until it works.  Here `Graphics[{{RGBColor[0.976577, 0.949233, 0.0195315], 
   Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}` definitely works, so start there.  Next add in the other graphics primitives until you find the point where it breaks.  Doing this step by step you'll find

1. Your `Graphics` isn't properly formatted, you have `Graphics[{g1, g2, g3},{g4, g5,...}]`  so it is interpreting that second list of graphics primitives as if they were options.  You need `Graphics[{g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,...}]`.
2. You have `Arrow[pt1, pt2]` but it needs to be `Arrow[{pt1, pt2}]`
3. One of your `Text` calls has 3 coordinates instead of 2.

[image]